# SQL ISDATE function not working

Tags: sql-server

I have date column in a SQL Server table in two different formats

- Format-1: dd/mm/yyyy
- Format-2: yyyy-mm-dd

I would like to change the format-1 to format 2 but the SQL throws an error.

please advise

```
update T1_fact
set wk_date = to_date(varchar, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
where is_date(varchar, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = 1
```

Comment: what  error is it throwing please specify.

Comment: which database you  are using? SQL Server?

Comment: `TO_DATE` is **not** a standard SQL function - it's an Oracle specific function which doesn't exist in SQL Server

Comment: SQL server 2008 n the error is

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'to_date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Try either `convert` or `cast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by **@marc** -->

*TO_DATE is not a standard SQL function - it's an Oracle specific function which doesn't exist in SQL Server*

So, for SQL Server, you would required to use `convert()` function in order to update your dates with standard format `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
update T1_fact
set wk_date = CONVERT(date, wk_date, 103)
--where is_date(varchar, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = 1
```